# In Rally, how to get initiative, feature and user story in a .CSV export?

Tags: rally

How do I use the Rally UI or Excel "CA Agile Central" add-in to get the initiative, feature and user story? I need to know the features under each initiative. I also need the user stories under each feature. (Initiative -> Feature -> User Story). Once this data is in a .CSV I can use Excel to pivot and filter.

Also, I'd prefer not to write code and call the API since this should be an easy set of data to extract.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of apps that already do most of this.  Custom List, which is already in the app catalog should make it easy to set up lists of features under a specific initiative and stories under a specific feature (or even all stories under features under a specific initiative).  You can also export directly from the app.

There is also a community app called Custom Chart that allows for some basic charting and uses the same filtering component as Custom List.  You can also export from this app.  It is available here: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/CustomChart and is installed using the Custom HTML app.

Does that get you closer?

Comment: I previously tried custom lists, however when you export from a custom list the .CSV only contains the top level node. In my case the top level node was an initiative. I expanded several nodes under an initiative, exported again and still only received the top level initiative in the .CSV. Am I missing a filtering option or other custom list config?

Comment: Ah, I see.  As far as I know there's not a way to get all of that data in one request...